# Sorting given text alphabetically w/o additional library

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, c++11

My homework was to write an application that sorts given text in alphabetically order. To do so, I was allowed only to use 'vector', 'string' and 'iostream' library.

I succeed but now struggling with strange problem - while I'm trying to sort a short text, everything works well but with longer inputs program seems to get into infinity loop or efficiency problem. Eg in text

```
"Albert Einstein 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955 was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the theory of relativity one of the two pillars of modern physics alongside quantum mechanics His work is also known[...]"
```

everything works great until "mechanics" phrase. After adding this, or any other word, program is running eternally like I mentioned before.

I'm afraid that I have to paste whole code in this case (please forgive).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int compare(std::string first, std::string second){
    int flag = 1;
    int i;
    if (first.size() <= second.size()){
        for (i = 0; i<first.size(); ++i ){
            if (first[i] == second[i]){
                continue;}
            else if (first[i] > second[i]){
                flag = 0;
                break;}
            else {
                break;}}}
    else {
        for (i = 0; i<second.size(); ++i ){
            if (first[i] == second[i]) {
                continue;}
            else if (first[i] > second[i]){
                flag = 0;
                break;}
            else {
                break;}
        }
        int m = second.size() - 1;
        if (first[m] == second[m]){
                flag = 0;}}
return flag;}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> text;
    std::string word;
    std::string tmp;
    while(std::cin >> word){
        text.push_back(word);}
    int mistakes, m = 1;
    while(m) {
        mistakes = 0;
        for (int index = 1; index < text.size() ; ++index){
            if (!(compare(text[index-1], text[index]))){
                tmp = text[index];
                text[index] = text[index-1];
                text[index-1] = tmp;
                mistakes += 1;}}
        m = mistakes;}
    for (auto element: text){
        std::cout << element << " ";}}
```

I would love to hear how to fix it and why exactly this problem appears - at least time of execution doesn't grow with lenght of input, but more like "work/doesn't work", what is unlike to efficency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had missed some conditions because of which your while loop running infinitely. For example:

1. Your **mistakes** variable on whose value your while loop executes never becomes 0, if the very first pair of words are in wrong order. Negative test case would be : "ball apple". In this case your code runs infinitely.
2. In your compare method because of following line of code test case like this "Apple ball" were giving wrong answers. Here first[m] = second[m] = l , thus according to your condition it will return false and swap them. It will swap "Apple" with "Ball" which is wrong.

   ```
   int m = second.size() - 1;
       if (first[m] == second[m]){
               flag = 0;
   }
   ```
3. You also need to handle the cases where there will be comparison between upper and lower case words. For example: "Month also". In this case answer should be "also Month". So before comparing two string you should bring them to same case and then compare.
4. Number comparison case where 1874 should come after 18. (you can add this)

> Following is the corrected code.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

int compare(std::string first, std::string second){

    // this is to handle the comparison of two words with mixed case(upper/lower) of letters.
    // earlier solution failed for comparison between 'Month' and 'a'
    for(int i=0;i<first.size();i++){
        first[i] = tolower(first[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<second.size();i++){
        second[i] = tolower(second[i]);
    }

    int flag = 1;
    int i;
    if (first.size() <= second.size()){
        for (i = 0; i<first.size(); ++i ){
            if (first[i] == second[i]){
                continue;}
            else if (first[i] > second[i]){
                flag = 0;
                break;}
            else {
                break;}}}
    else {
        for (i = 0; i<second.size(); ++i ){
            if (first[i] == second[i]) {
                continue;}
            else if (first[i] > second[i]){
                flag = 0;
                break;}
            else {
                break;}
        }

    }
    return flag;}


    int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> text;
    std::string word;
    std::string tmp;
    while(std::cin >> word){
        text.push_back(word);}



    // bubble short
    for(int i=0;i<(text.size()-1);i++){

        for(int j=0;j<(text.size()-1-i);j++){
            if (!(compare(text[j], text[j+1]))){
                tmp = text[j];
                text[j] = text[j+1];
                text[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }



    for (auto element: text){
        std::cout << element << " ";}}
```